# SQLite databe does not create table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having trouble creating an SQLite database. The program runs fine until I try to access the database in an Activity, when it crashes. I suspect there is something wrong with the code that creates the tables, but I can't find the error.

Viewing the logcat of my device while trying to add data to the database, I see these entries:

`table scoretable has no column named persons_score` and

`Error inserting persons_score=10 persons_name=me` and

`blablaSQLiteException: table scoretable has no column named persons_score (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO scoretable (persons_score,persons_name) VALUES (?,?)`

Here is the code:

**HighScore: (the database class)**

```
    public class HighScore {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
    public static final String KEY_SCORE = "persons_score";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "highscoredb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "scoretable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){



            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_SCORE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public HighScore(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public HighScore open(){


        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String name, String resultat){

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_SCORE, resultat);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public String getData(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iScore = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE);

        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iScore) + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**Results.java** (where the user can see his score and choose to add it to the database, when clicking the viewHighscore button the app crashes.)

```
    public class Resultat extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button addHighScore, viewHighScore;
    TextView dittResultat;
    int resultat;
    String name;
    String stringResultat;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.resultat);

        addHighScore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addhighscore);
        viewHighScore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewhighscore);
        dittResultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dittresultat);

        addHighScore.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHighScore.setOnClickListener(this);


        Globals g = (Globals)getApplication();
        resultat = g.getData();
        String name = ((Globals) this.getApplication()).getTypedName();


        dittResultat.setText("Gratulerer " + name + " , du har gjennomført quizen og fikk" + resultat + " av 10 riktige!" );
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0){

        switch (arg0.getId()){

            case R.id.addhighscore:

                boolean didItWork = true;
                try{
                Globals g = (Globals)getApplication();
                name = ((Globals) this.getApplication()).getTypedName();
                resultat = g.getData();
                stringResultat = Integer.toString(resultat);


                HighScore entry = new HighScore(Resultat.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(name, stringResultat);
                entry.close();

                }catch (Exception e){
                    didItWork = false;
                    String error = e.toString();
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("NEI!");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(error);
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                } finally{
                    if(didItWork){
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Wee!");
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setText("Det funka!");
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();
                    }
                }

                break;

            case R.id.viewhighscore:

                Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(Resultat.this, HighScoreView.class);

                startActivity(myIntent2);

                break;

        }
    }


}
```

**List.java** (simple textview that tries to display the results of a database query, opening this class crashes the app).

```
   public class HighScoreView extends Activity {

    TextView liste;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscoreview);

        liste = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.liste);

        HighScore hsListe = new HighScore(this);
        hsListe.open();
        String data = hsListe.getData();
        hsListe.close();
        liste.setText(data);


    }

}
```

Comment: Post your Error log file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably added the `persons_score` column after your database was created. Just do a clear data for your app, or uninstall and then re-run the app.

That should fix it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Did add more tables/columns recently? Try to uninstall your app and install it again to go through the creation again. Database is created only once so the code in `onCreate` is not called again when you upgrade your app.

Comment: Holy smokes that fixed it lol! I've been hammering my head in my desk for like 5 hours haha. Thanks to you and Neil!

Answer (score 0):

Its probably cause you have added columns recently after creation of data in your device, seeing from code pasted here i can't figure out any thing wrong in it.

Point is whenever you change your database schema you need to change version number to something higher than previous, otherwise android will fail to upgrade your database failing onUpgrade to execute. so even though you did correct, you database failed to register change.

so as a resolution, uninstall and install your app or change database version and reinstall it . Make sure for you future reference, specially when your app goes live, track you database version and always change it if you change schema.